# ajax and php, ajax success not working

Tags: php, ajax

Hi I am using ajax and php with an update query. My ajax success function does not work. Here is my ajax call and my php page.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/db.php?argument=updateStock",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == 'successful'){
             alert("Good");
        }else{
            alert("Fail");
        } 
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("ERROR");
    }
});
```

This is my php code.

```
if($_GET['argument']=='updateStock'){
    $ids = explode(',', $_POST['updateId']);
    $values = explode(',', $_POST['updateVal']);

    for($x=0; $x < $ids; $x++){
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE clinic_medicine_stock SET 
        stock_ammount = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, 
        $values[$x]) . "' WHERE medicine_uuid = '" . 
        mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $ids[$x]) . "'");

        echo "successful";
    }

    mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    //close connection to db
    mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

I cant figure out why my ajax success is not working, Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Define "does not work."  What *does* it do?  What is the response from the server?  When you step through it in a debugger, what happens?

Comment: You are outputting `successful` in a loop so I would not be surprised if the complete output / `data` variable contains that word multiple times instead of just once.

Comment: the ajax success does not trigger, in the console under header I get Status Code:200 OK

Comment: Assuming you get the ERROR-Alert: You could add a parameter to the error-handler like `error: function(data) {` and output that parameter inside the error handler with `console.log`. That might give you a clue what is going wrong in your php code. My guess is that a PHP Error is occurring somewhere in your PHP code.

Comment: by the way, before executing success queries, you are calling "successful" is a bad idea. And i suspect the problem just lies to here, you are echoing too many "successful"

Comment: First of all, precise what you get, what's output. Secondly, use Firebug or Chrome's Inspector to check what is HTML response (I don't mean headers but content) to your `XHR`. Lastly, you got echo in loop in php code and possibly you closed php with `?>` and made empty whitespaces after it which affects data sent back to ajax